# Converting C to NASM assembly with segmentation issue

Tags: c, nasm, fault

I'm trying to get this c code:

```
main()

 {int x, y, count ;

  count = 0 ;
  x = 10 ; 
  y = 2 ;
  while (y < x)
    { x = x + 1 ;
      y = y + 2 ;
      count = count + 1 ;
     } 

    printf(“ It took %d iterations to complete loop. That seems like a     lot\n”,count) ;
}
```

to its NASM equivalent which I have this so far:

```
segment .data

out1    db "It took ", 0
out2    db "%i ", 0
out3    db "iterations to complete the loop. That seems like a lot.", 10, 0

segment .bss

segment .text

global     main
extern printf

main:

    mov    eax, 0        ;count
    mov    ebx, 10        ;x
    mov    ecx, 2        ;y

    jmp     lp

    mov    eax, 0
    ret

lp:
    cmp    ecx, ebx    ;compare y to x
    jge    end        ;jump to end if y >= x
    add    eax, 1
    add    ebx, 1
    add    ecx, 2
    jmp    lp

end:

    push    out1
    call    printf

   push    eax
   push    out2
   call    printf

   push    out3
   call    printf
```

I keep getting a segmentation fault and I don't understand why it keeps happening. I've tried adding in print statements everywhere and cannot find where the fault is located. Any advice would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Your asm seems okay to me.

Comment: Do you have a `ret` instruction after the `printf`s?

Comment: yes i've tired that it didn't take care of the segmentation problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not following the calling convention for `printf` (it's [cdecl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) IIRC).

1. the caller must clean the stack after the call
2. and eax is clobbered by the first call to `printf` with it's return value

Number one will cause trouble when returning from `main`. Actually, there is no `ret` instruction after the `printf`s which causes the execution to go on until something goes wrong :)

Add the following after printing:

```
   add     esp, 16  ; Fix stack, usually it's done after each call
                    ; with the appropiate values.
                    ; In this way (one fixup for many calls) stack
                    ; grows unnecessarily
   xor     eax, eax ; set return value to 0
   ret              ; Return from main
```

Although, this does not take care of issue number two.

Comment: Thanks that actually helped quite a bit I'll see if it works.

Comment: Diego, since this is a stand-alone assembly program, there is no `main` and no need to return. What is needed is to make a syscall to exit to cleanup on program termination. The exit code is set in `ebx`, the **x86** syscall for exit is `1` (see: `/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h`) and goes in `eax`, then the kernel is called to execute the command `int 0x80` or `int 80h`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Making an exit system call instead of returning is obviously fine, but this program clearly does have a `main` function. Most assembly programs linking to the standard C library will have one.

Comment: Could you guys also look at this code for me really quick as well? It also having a segmentation issue which I'm not able to figure out. Its a similar exercise where we take a c program and create a nasm program from it.                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956567/nasm-assembly-mathematical-logic

Answer (score 0):

Updated and complete example:

```
segment .data
out1    db      "It took %d iterations to complete loop. That seems like "
        db      "a lot.", 0aH, 00H
segment .bss
segment .text
        global  main
        extern  printf
main:   xor     eax, eax
        mov     ebx, 10
        mov     ecx, 2
loop0:  inc     ebx
        add     ecx, 2
        inc     eax
        cmp     ecx, ebx
        jl      loop0
        push    eax
        push    offset out1
        call    printf
        add     esp, 8
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
        end
```

Comment: i'm still getting the segmentation fault with the changes

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't got it sorted out yet, the issue is due to `eax` getting thrashed on your `printf` call. How to fix? Save it to a buffer before the first `printf` call and load `eax` before the second. E.g. add:

```
segment .bss

buffer resd  1          ; reserve 32 bit buffer
...
mov     [buffer], eax   ; save eax in the buffer

push    out1
call    printf

mov     eax, [buffer]   ; load eax from the buffer

push    eax
push    out2
call    printf

push    out3
call    printf

xor     ebx, ebx         ; exit nicely 
mov     eax, 1
int     0x80
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/pt
It took 8 iterations to complete the loop. That seems like a lot.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd waste time and effort coding up a buffer for it when you have a perfectly good stack just sitting around, waiting to be used :-) In other words, `push eax`, `pop eax`.