# NASM Assembly mathematical logic

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, logic, nasm

I have a program in assembly for the Linux terminal that's supposed to work through a series of mathematical manipulations, compare the final value to 20, and then using if logic, report <, > or = relationship. Code is:

```
segment .data

out_less     db "Z is less than 20.", 10, 0
out_greater  db "Z is greater than 20.", 10, 0
out_equal    db "Z is equal to 20.", 10, 0

segment .bss

segment .text

global main
extern printf

main:

    mov    eax, 10
    mov    ebx, 12
    mov    ecx, eax
    add    ecx, ebx    ;set c (ecx reserved)

    mov    eax, 3
    mov    ebx, ecx
    sub    ebx, eax    ;set f (ebx reserved)

    mov    eax, 12
    mul    ecx
    add    ecx, 10     ;(a+b*c) (ecx reserved)

    mov    eax, 6
    mul    ebx
    mov    eax, 3
    sub    eax, ebx
    mov    ebx, eax    ;(d-e*f) (ebx reserved) reassign to ebx to free eax

    mov    eax, ecx
    div    ebx
    add    ecx, 1      ;(a+b*c)/(d-e*f) + 1

    cmp    ecx, 20
    jl     less
    jg     greater
    je     equal

    mov    eax, 0
    ret

less:

    push    out_less
    call    printf
    jmp     end

greater:

    push    out_greater
    call    printf
    jmp     end

equal:

    push    out_equal
    call    printf
    jmp     end

end:

    mov     eax, 0
    ret
```

Commands for compiling in terminal using nasm and gcc:

```
nasm -f elf iftest.asm
gcc -o iftest iftest.o
./iftest
```

Equivalent C code would be:

```
main() {
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, z;
    a = 10;
    b = 12;
    c = a + b;
    d = 3;
    e = 6;
    f = c - d;
    z = ((a + b*c) / (d - e*f)) + 1;

    if (z < 20) {
        printf("Z (%d) is less than 20.\n", z);
    }
    else if (z > 20) {
        printf("Z is greater than 20.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Z is equal to 20.\n");
    }
}
```

The current output is incorrect. The C code will report that z = -1, and therefore less than 20, but the assembly code outputs `Z is greater than 20.` I've tried printing out the final value, but I run into this issue where printing the value somehow changes it. I've checked and rechecked the math logic and I can't see why it shouldn't give the correct value, unless I'm using the math operators incorrectly. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Be aware that `div 32-bit-reg` divides the 64-bit word in `edx:eax` by `reg`, so you need to initialize `edx` before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
div    ebx
add    ecx, 1      ;(a+b*c)/(d-e*f) + 1
```

The result of the `div` instruction is not in `ecx`.

Comment: Am I incorrect in thinking that the div command is passed the divisor and then uses the last used register for the dividend? I'm an absolute beginner so my understanding is very limited.

Comment: @vroom: Yes, that is incorrect. The `div` instruction has no idea what the "last used register" is. It also puts the quotient and remainder in specific registers, neither of which are `ecx`.

Comment: Oh, I see now what the problem is. `div` works on the `eax` register, which was assigned `ecx`, so after `div` is called I need to reassign `ecx` with `mov ecx, eax`

Comment: Sure, or just use `eax` in the following `add` and `cmp` instructions.